# Как принимать кукисы с помощью curl

Tags: curl, php

Здравствуйте, есть функция для того, чтоб брать содержимое сайта:

```
function getContent($url){
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
return $page;
}

$content = getContent('тут какой-нибудь сайт');
```

Эта функция не берёт содержимое сайта если он требует работу с кукисами, т.е. как дополнить эту функцию чтоб прежде чем она брала содержимое сайта, она сначала принимала кукисы и потом отправляла их же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл cookie.txt, выставьте права записи 0777 на него, и добавьте в свой код строки:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```